# Master page image doesn't display on content page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an image on my master page like this:

```
<img src="../Images/logo.jpg" />
```

The master page lies in `Root/MasterPages/masterpage.master`

Now this image is displayed in a content page which is in `Root/SomeDir/ContentPage.aspx`,
but it doesn't work in a content page which is in `Root/SomeDir1/SomeDir2/ContentPage.aspx`. Why?

Master Page HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <style type="text/css">
        #div_Main
        {
            height: 825px;
            width: 1022px;
            top: 16px;
            left: 77px;
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: 14px;
        }
        #div_LeftPanel
        {
            width: 299px;
            top: 179px;
            left: 2px;
            position: absolute;
            height: 641px;
            background-color: #7E8387;
        }
        #div_Content
        {
            width: 716px;
            top: 180px;
            left: 303px;
            position: absolute;
            height: 638px;
        }
        #div_Header
        {
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            height: 176px;
            width: 1022px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="div_Main">
      <div id="div_Header">
          <img src="../Images/logo.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div id="div_Content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cph_WorkingArea" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      </div>


      <div id="div_LeftPanel">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton 
              ID="lnkbtn_JObAspirantsList" runat="server" 
              style="color: #CFCFF3; font-size: xx-large" 
              onclick="lnkbtn_JObAspirantsList_Click">Job Aspirants List</asp:LinkButton>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn_ERFList" runat="server" 
              style="color: #CFCFF3; font-size: xx-large" onclick="lnkbtn_ERFList_Click">ERF List</asp:LinkButton>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn_InterviewFeedbackList" runat="server" 
              style="color: #CFCFF3; font-size: xx-large" 
              onclick="lnkbtn_InterviewFeedbackList_Click">Interview FeedbackList</asp:LinkButton>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn_NewEmployeeList" runat="server" 
              style="color: #CFCFF3; font-size: xx-large" 
              onclick="lnkbtn_NewEmployeeList_Click">New Employees List</asp:LinkButton>
            <br />
          <br />
          <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" style="color: #CFCFF3; font-size: xx-large"  onclick="LinkButton1_Click">LogOut</asp:LinkButton>
          <br />
          <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </div>
     </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Content Page HTML

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/HRMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ERF.aspx.cs" Inherits="StarTechnologies.ERF" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cph_WorkingArea" runat="server">


    <p>
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Height="212px" 
            onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="434px">
        </asp:GridView>
    </p>
    <br />


</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RPM1984 is almost right. You should use `~` to indicate a path relative to the root of your application. You should however translate that to a path the browser understands. If you are using ASP.NET controls like Image that is done automatically. If you're using HTML tags (without `runat="server"`) you have to translate the path manually using [Page.ResolveClientUrl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx).

For example:

```
<img src="<%= ResolveClientUrl( "~/Images/logo.jpg" ) %>"/>
```

In this case however, you're probably better off using the Image control:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/logo.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Even this is not working for me. While I use this I cannot see the image even in the master page.

Comment: Yeah this is working. But why?
I mean what's wrong with <img src="<%= ResolveClientUrl( "~/Images/logo.jpg" ) %>"/>

Comment: @Nadeem There's nothing wrong with it technically. Mixing server code with HTML is considered a 'bad thing' by many people because it makes your markup harder to read. If you anticipate someone else will someday need to maintain this site you should make it easy to read and understand the markup an code.

Comment: @Marnix van Valen: So this is about bad practice. That's Okay. But in my case <img src="<%= ResolveClientUrl( "~/Images/logo.jpg" ) %>"/> is not working at all. Not even on the master page. Forget about the content pages.

Comment: @Nadeem Have you checked the HTML source in the browser? What path is generated for the image?

Comment: @Nadeem - try to stop thinking "it doesnt work, not even on the master page". There IS NO masterpage once it's rendered to the client - the end result is a page which is created by ASP.NET based on combining the masterpage/contentpage. Think of the masterpage as a "base class", not a seperate HTML page.

Comment: Yeah that's right but I was talking about master page designer. I mean I could not see the image on master page designer.

Comment: But I tried closing and reopening Visual Studio and this worked for me. And now ResolveClientUrl is also working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try not to use relative paths.

Use absolute:

```
<img src="~/Images/logo.jpg" />
```

That is assuming "Images" is a folder underneath the root of your web application.

The thing to remember about Master Pages is that they really are *syntactic sugar* in a way (similar to partial classes) That is, when you put an image inside a MasterPage, the .NET CLR will create the content page with the Master info - so the image reference will be *unchanged*.

It's not **../Images** from the Master, its **../Images** from the Content it's placed upon.

In other words, to the **client**, there is only ONE page (ASPX - content page), it's not like a magical parent page has been created which holds onto URL references.

HTH

Comment: Yeah I tried this but when I use ~ the image is not displayed even on the master page.

Comment: What do you mean "on the master page". Can you show your masterpage HTML and content page HTML where it's not workgin?

Comment: The image lives in /Root/Images/logo.jpg? Just use an absolute path <img src="/Root/Images/logo.jpg"> - relative paths, master pages, and content pages in different directories just do not play nicely together.

Comment: @Carson63000 - that's what i said in my answer (~ and / are the same AFAIK)

Comment: @RPM1984: When I say on the Master page I mean on the designer of Master page.

Comment: @RPM1984 - don't forget that ~ only works on runat=server controls - if you serve up <img src="~/Images/logo.jpg" /> to the browser it won't work.

Comment: @Carson63000 - youre right, i always forget the difference between ~ and /, thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

My master page's content didn't display but the Web Form content did.
What happens is that the content page is overwritting the master page's content.

I solved it creating a new ContentPlaceHolder in the MasterPage with ID="Example".

Then in the Web Form, I changed *ContentPlaceholderID="OlderID"* to **ContentPlacerHolderID="Example"**.